# What is the O-difficulty of logarithmic for-cycle with logarithmic operation inside it?

Tags: big-o

What is the Big O Notation for the code, where you have some logarithmic for-cycle with logarithmic operation inside of it, e.g.:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i*2) {
    binarySearchTree.add(i);
 }
```

O(log(n))*O(log(n))=O(log(n)*log(n)), can it be further simplified?

Comment: Well you can at least represent `log(n) * log(n)` as `(log(n))^2`

Comment: This is O(infinity) because `i` will never increase. Did you mean to write `int i = 1;` instead?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. It should be int i = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big O Notations behave the same as regular math expressions, if you keep in mind that O(n) is an unspecified linear function, so you are allowed to combine this to:

```
O(log(n)) * O(log(n)) = O(log(n)²)
```

Within math, this is pretty much all you can do. When it comes to estimating the performance of something (which is what the Big-O-Notation is good for), you might want to go a step further:

When compared to O(log(n)) and O(n), your algorithm is *much* closer to the former than the latter. For high values of n (e.g. 1e10), you get:

- O(log(n)) = O(10)
- O(log(n)²) = O(100)
- O(n) = O(10000000000)

So unless your operation is working with a small *n*, *O(log(n))* and *O(log(n)²)* operate very similar when compared to a linear operation O(n). Similar in such a way that differences in the computational effort per operation might outweigh it.